# Android - NullPointerException on logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground

Tags: java, android, facebook, parsing

I'm trying to use the Facebook login from Parse but I'm having an issue.

I have this error :

```
05-11 11:12:29.989  14760-14760/com.picmate D/ContextHelper﹕ convertTheme. context->name=com.picmate themeResourceId=2131492865
05-11 11:12:29.998  14760-14760/com.picmate I/PhoneWindow﹕ [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff000001
05-11 11:12:30.008  14760-14760/com.picmate D/PhoneWindowEx﹕ [LMJ][PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
05-11 11:12:30.008  14760-14760/com.picmate I/PhoneWindow﹕ [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
05-11 11:12:30.029  14760-14793/com.picmate D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Render dirty regions requested: true
05-11 11:12:30.030  14760-14793/com.picmate I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
Build Date: 12/12/14 금
Local Branch: LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.031_20141212_01821442
Remote Branch:
Local Patches:
Reconstruct Branch:
05-11 11:12:30.033  14760-14793/com.picmate I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-11 11:12:30.061  14760-14793/com.picmate D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
05-11 11:12:30.072  14760-14760/com.picmate D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
05-11 11:12:30.347  14760-14760/com.picmate I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3c12cf43 time:189759021
05-11 11:12:33.150  14760-14760/com.picmate I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-11 11:12:33.207  14760-14760/com.picmate I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-11 11:12:33.254  14760-14760/com.picmate I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.picmate time:189761928
05-11 11:12:33.330  14760-14760/com.picmate D/ContextHelper﹕ convertTheme. context->name=com.picmate themeResourceId=2131492865
05-11 11:12:33.360  14760-14760/com.picmate I/PhoneWindow﹕ [generateLayout] setColorNavigationBar => color=0x ff00000105-11
05-11 11:12:33.361  14760-14760/com.picmate D/PhoneWindowEx﹕ [LMJ][PWEx][generateLayout] setNavigationBarColor2 : colors=0xff000000
05-11 11:12:33.362  14760-14760/com.picmate I/PhoneWindow﹕ [setNavigationBarColor2] color=0x ff000000
05-11 11:12:33.822  14760-14760/com.picmate I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@3e31cc52 time:189762497
05-11 11:12:35.374  14760-14760/com.picmate I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
05-11 11:12:35.441  14760-14760/com.picmate I/ViewRootImpl﹕ ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
05-11 11:12:35.483  14760-14760/com.picmate D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-11 11:12:35.486  14760-14760/com.picmate E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.picmate, PID: 14760
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.getLogger(LoginManager.java:391)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.logCompleteLogin(LoginManager.java:414)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.startLogin(LoginManager.java:384)
        at com.facebook.login.LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(LoginManager.java:262)
        at com.parse.FacebookAuthenticationProvider.authenticateAsync(FacebookAuthenticationProvider.java:155)
        at com.parse.ParseAuthenticationProvider.logInAsync(ParseAuthenticationProvider.java:50)
        at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInAsync(ParseFacebookUtils.java:265)
        at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(ParseFacebookUtils.java:161)
        at com.parse.ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(ParseFacebookUtils.java:173)
        at com.picmate.ConnectionActivity$1.onClick(ConnectionActivity.java:46)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4763)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19821)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5274)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

My code is :

```
        final Collection<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();;

    permissions.add("user_status");
    permissions.add("read_stream");

    findViewById(R.id.btnFB).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(ConnectionActivity.this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                    if (user == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(ConnectionActivity.this, "Error Sabatie in da place", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (user.isNew()) {
                        Toast.makeText(ConnectionActivity.this, "Inscription + login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ConnectionActivity.this, "login solo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

My code at the line 46 is :

```
  ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(ConnectionActivity.this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
```

I can't solve this issue since two days, I tried to debug and look on internet but I didn't find a solution yet.

Please if someone can help me.

Comment: what is line no 391 in LoginManager.java ?

Comment: I don't know, it's from the "LoginManager.class" and it's compiled code

Comment: Could you please post your full logcat please..

Comment: I just edited with the full logcat since the launch of the application

Comment: Ur Facebook request Object is null here..have a breakpoint there and debbug the case !

Comment: What do you call the Facebook request object ?
I already put a breakpoint but nothing seems wrong

Comment: Are you initializing Facebook correctly and setting your application ID on the initialization of your application? Also have you associated your Parse account with your Facebook in your Parse application settings?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue yesterday and spent hours trying to figure what was causing the NullPointerException from Facebook's LoginManager.
Turns out I found an answer stating pretty clearly this has to comes from a mistake in the AndroidManifest.xml, when you need to precisely insert this :

```
<application>
    ...
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    ...
    </application>
```

Mine had the first line twisted to android:name=" com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
(with an extra space between " and the c).
As I'm pretty sure I didn't typed it in myself but c/ced it from somewhere else, I guess others will end up with the same extra space...

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, and after adding the meta data for the application ID and application name like so:

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationName"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_name" />
```

I got another error, so I had to add the facebook activity to the manifest as well:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```